# Operations similar to Clojure's get-in and assoc-in for plists

Tags: clojure, common-lisp, property-list

I'm using property lists in Common Lisp to represent a binary tree with some additional information. I'd like to be able to dig arbitrarily deep into the tree with a single function, and also modify it accordingly.

In Clojure (which is the other Lisp I use), there exist functions called `get-in` and `assoc-in` which can do exactly this, but I haven't found anything similar in Common Lisp. Do they actually exist, or am I going to have to write them?

Comment: For those of us less familiar with Clojure, can you show how those functions are used?  What would an ideal Common Lisp counterpart look like?  Do they take a list of keys or something?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor: Suppose I had a plist ``*pl*`` as follows: ``(:a 1 :b (:a 2 :b 3))``. Then, ``(get-in *pl* '(:b :a))`` would give me ``2``, and ``(assoc-in *pl* '(:b :a) 5)`` would return ``(:a 1 :b (:a 5 :b 3))``.

Comment: @MrSinister13: can you edit your question to add the additional information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not yet seen the use of nested plists for such a data structure; it may be somewhat unusual.  I'd rather expect a structure (defined with `defstruct`) or class (defined with `defclass`) representing nodes.  An alternative for the case of (not too sparse) binary trees is the implementation as an array, where the root node is at index 0 and each node's children at (2 · i + 1) and (2 · i + 2).

If you insist on using plists, you will have to nest `getf`s and write a `setf` expander for nested `getf`s.